# Charge distribution and Electric field due to spheres touching each other

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy

I have two conducting spheres, one of radius **a** and other of **b**(a > b) having charges q<sub>1</sub> and q<sub>2</sub> respectively. Now, I brought sphere 2 closer to sphere 1 and made them touch each other.
[image]

I know that charges will be distributed such that Potential of Sphere 1 will be equal to that of Sphere 2 and I can find the charges.

I have the following doubts :

1. How are charges distributed on individual sphere? Are they uniform on **each** sphere or on system?
2. I can easily calculate Electric Field or Self Energy anywhere if the charges are distributed uniformly on both spheres but If not, How can I calculate it?

Comment: Yes, both are conducting.

Comment: I have edited the question also.

Comment: This is an advanced problem. See Appendix B of [this paper](https://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~podgornik/download/Lekner-attraction.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If radiuses of spheres are quite big, then potential [approaches point-charge potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation#Potential_of_a_Gaussian_charge_density). Equating two point charge potentials $\varphi_R = \varphi_r$, you can get total charge ratio on the spheres (assuming same permittivity):

$$ {\frac {Q_R}{Q_r}} = {\frac {R}{r}},$$

So when radiuses are not equal, $\to R\ne r$, then follows that $Q_R \ne Q_r$.

As about question of charge distribution uniformity, charges on the sphere must react not only to $Q_{local}$, but also to $Q_{neighbour}$, so at least something different must happen near contact zones, where interacting field intensities are strongest. So, I believe that charge distribution on single sphere is non-uniform either.